# How to jump to the start/end of a function in IDA disassembly?

Tags: ida

Simple question that I coudn't find googling: if I'm in the middle of a function how can I jump to the start/end (prologue/epilogue) of this function in IDA's disassembly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe there is a hotkey that will do it by default. One solution you could have is to add something like this to your `.idapythonrc`

```
# define functions to do the jumping
def jump_func_start():
    Jump(GetFunctionAttr(here(), FUNCATTR_START))

def jump_func_end():
    Jump(PrevHead(GetFunctionAttr(here(), FUNCATTR_END)))

# Compile IDC wrappers to call the python
idaapi.CompileLine('static j_f_start() { RunPythonStatement("jump_func_start()"); }')
idaapi.CompileLine('static j_f_end() { RunPythonStatement("jump_func_end()"); }')

# Add the hotkey
AddHotkey("Ctrl-Alt-K", 'j_f_start')
AddHotkey("Ctrl-Alt-J", 'j_f_end')
```

After that you can just type whatever hotkey you set and it should go to the start / end of the function

Comment: Hum that's odd. IDA is such a powerful tool but it kinda seems to have a lot of missing nice simple features. Other example of such is the sintax highlight, it doesn't even have the possibility of change the color of specific instructions. Sometimes I find myself wanting to generate a .dbg of the IDB and go to the olly/x64dbg to do static analysis due to the lack of these features. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Not sure about changing the syntax colors from the default. I know some people use themes in IDA. If you just want to color the instruction, there's a ColorInstruction command (Edit | Other | Color instruction) you can set  a hotkey for it by searching for ColorInstruction in the shortcuts menu (Options | Shortcuts). I commonly use that when reversing along with GraphColor / GraphDefaultColor to markup IDBs with paths taken

Comment: Ctrl-P, Enter works for start.